# Add inputListener to texture

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx

I have written a game in libgdx. Everything works fine, except one thing:

When the player loses, a "Game Over" texture gets displayed to the screen. I'd like to add a "tap screen to restart" function to the game, but to do this, I need to attach an eventListener to the whole texture.

Is this possible? If not, what can I do?

Edit:

Here's my texture declaration and use:

declaration:

```
private final Texture gameOver;
```

create() method:

```
gameOver = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/pali/BROKE.png"));
gameOver.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

render() method:

```
//rest of the method ommited for clarity
spriteBatch.draw(gameOver, 0, 0);
```

Comment: is the texture a component?

Comment: I'm not really sure what a component is. I edited the question with the code I used.

Comment: can you not just capture a mouse/tap event for the whole screen? (I don't do android development, just Java)

Comment: I'm not sure. If I'm right, you first need to attach an Event Handler to the object wich's events you want to be captured, but I'm unsure how to attach it to a texture.

Comment: Is there something behind the Texture which you can attach an Event Handler to? My guess is that if the Texture can't catch an Event, then the events probably occur as though it wasn't there

Comment: can you attach it to spriteBatch?

Comment: No, but I was doing the wrong thing. You were right mentioning, that I should add a listener to the whole screen, this is what I did. If you could submit that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually easier than I thought. I just had to implement InputProcessor within the class and generate the missing methods. After that I had az InputListener inside my class, so I could listen to events to the whole screen.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor  {
// ...
// rest of the class ommited for clarity
@Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(gameOver){
            clearGame();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe post the code that worked for you, in case others come looking for this same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an android developer, but you should be able to attach a listener to the whole screen to listen to taps. (Comment made as answer as requested by OP) See the OPs own answer for the final solution.